# Today Extension: Cant reload tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I created a today extension/widget. I implemented a table view. If the widget runs and stepped into the viewDidLoad function where I wrote this line of code: `tableView.reloaData()` the tableView doesn't reload and the next line of code runs. 
My viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    updateSize()
}
```

Does someone knows why the tableView doesn't reloads?

Comment: Is the tableView's dataSource set (and does the data source have any [new] data?

Comment: Is there a new data added to the tableview? .reloadData() only works, if there is.

Comment: I set the delegate and dataSource programmatically. Now it works.